# Past perfect with 2nd conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

Let's consider this situation: There was a test last Monday and I cheated on that test, so I tell a friend:

> If the teacher found out, they would fail me.

and I also wanna tell my friend that the teacher might imply that they've found out about it and given me a fail grade **already** by winking, so I say:

> If the teacher winked at me, that would mean they **had failed** me
> already.

does the last sentence express what I want to express?, if not, how do I express that in english?

Another example:

> If the teacher winked at me, I would know that they **had failed** me already

would the sentence above be correct even if at the moment of speaking the teacher **hasn't** failed me yet?, or does the action (failed) have to be done **by** the moment of speaking in order for the sentence to be correct?.

I'm assuming that the sentences above describe things that could happen, even if not probable.

Comment: *If God spoke to me, I would know that He **existed**.* But I can't for the life of me see any difference in meaning, logic, OR "grammaticality" if I change that to *...I would know that He **exists**.* It's just that we *usually* "backshift" in such contexts (same as *He **said** his name **was** Smith*, even though it still ***is*** at time of utterance).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  So backshifting can take place even when talking about situations that didn't happen?, do we use backshifting with the 2nd conditional? (conditionals about situations that aren't happening and probably won't).  "He said his name was Smith" is an action that **did** happen.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but I doubt "numbered conditionals" are relevant here (they're a pretty worthless syntactic concept, imho). In your example *If the teacher winked at me, that would mean they had failed me already*, that initial ***if-** condition* could in principle be a reference to something that happened regularly in the past. But you've given enough context that we know you're talking about a ***hypothetical future*** (same as my ***If God spoke to me...***).

Comment: ...note that although I'm quite happy with ***if*** + Past Tense in my "God" example, it could have been expressed using Present Tense: *If God **speaks** to me, I **will** know that He **exists***. By the same token, your example could be phrased as *If the teacher **winks** at me, that **will** mean they **have** failed me already.* For reasons I'm not quite sure of right now, I think although both versions are fine for my example, yours works much better using Present rather than Past tense for the initial ***if-*** clause.